# how to test a method that takes two List arguments in Xunit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net

I have a method to Test that takes two arguments. one is  a list of list of string and other is just a list of int. method requires both the arguments as it does some logic inside  based on both arguments. I am not sure how to write  a unit test sending both the arguments. I was ok if method took only one arguments. Below is my test method

```
[Theory]
        [ClassData(typeof(CompetitionsTestData))]
        public void TestMethod(List<List<string>> x, List<int> y)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.WriteLine(y);
            string result=TournamentWinner.GetTournamentWinner(x, y);
            Assert.Equal("PYTHON", result.ToUpper());
        }
```

I created CompetitionsTestData so that I can create the Test Data

```
 public class CompetitionsTestData : IEnumerable<object[]>
    {
        public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
        {
            yield return new object[] {
                new List<List<string>>()
                {
                    new List<string>(){"HTML","C#"},
                    new List<string>(){"C#","PYTHON"},
                    new List<string>(){ "PYTHON", "HTML" }
                }
             };
           /*   yield return new object[] {
                new List<int>()
                {1,2,4 }
                
            };*/
        }
```

Above syntax is wrong. It only creates first argument(i removed the commented code as well). I am not sure how to send the second argument i.e List y. All blogs etc talk only about 1 argument. Also, ClassData only takes one argument too. Any help is appreciated...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually i found the answer on my own..posting here as it may help others

**code:unit test**

```
public class CompetitionsTestData : IEnumerable<object[]>
    {
        public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
        {
            yield return new object[] {
                new List<List<string>>()
                {
                    new List<string>(){"HTML","C#"},
                    new List<string>(){"C#","PYTHON"},
                    new List<string>(){ "PYTHON", "HTML" }
                },
                new List<int>()
                {1,2,4 }

             };            
        }
...
```